# What is a visual bag of words and how is it implemented?

Tags: image-processing, classification

I'm currently working on implementing a bag of visual words in Python. I get the general gist of how it works but I can't seem to find any sources that explain it in more detail to a level where I can implement it. I'm guessing scikit learn and scikit image would come in but I can't seem to point myself in the right direction. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

This is the original paper:

Gabriella Csurka, Christopher R. Dance, Lixin Fan, Jutta Willamowski, and  Cédric Bray. [Visual Categorization with Bag of Keypoints](http://www3.xrce.xerox.com/content/download/16582/118437/file/2004_010.pdf). Workshop on Statistical Learning in Computer Vision, ECCV, 2004.